# jQuery click() method translated to Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a jQuery code:

```
$('.class i').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input').click();
});
```

Which adds click method to the sibling element when `<i>` element is clicked.

```
<div class="class">
    <input>
    <i>
</div>
```

What would be the same syntax using Angular?

What I have now is:

```
<div class="class">
    <input>
    <i ng-click="onMyClickFunction($event)">
</div>
```

```js
onMyClickFunction = function(event){
    angular.element(event.target).parent().find('input').click();
}
```

I am using Angular's jqLite. But Angular's jqLite has no `click()` method. This `click()` method is a native javascript which is not cross-browser supported plus is not supported on mobile devices.

Comment: Maybe you want to use | angular.element('#myselector').trigger('click');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to not do this using javascript. Just use the default browser behavior, when you click on a label for an input, the input is selected. You could do this with 2 different approaches:

Simply wrap the input and the icon in a label

```
<label class="class">
    <input>
    <i>
</label>
```

Or you could use the `for` attribute

```
<div class="class">
    <input id="{{ $id }}">
    <label for="{{ $id }}"><i></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess this is the best solution to the problem. Thank you for thinking this through.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trigger('click')` instead:

```
onMyClickFunction = function(event){
    angular.element(event.target).parent().find('input').trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: downvoters never do. Coward. 
Anyway thanks for your effort. I up-voted you for the change.

Answer (score 0):

Write a directive,

```
app.directive('clickThis', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element) {

        element.bind('click', function(e) {
            angular.element(e.target).clickThis('.class').find('input').trigger('click');
        });
      }
    };
});
```

And your html would be,

```
<div class="class">
    <input>
    <i clickThis>
</div>
```

Where **`clickThis`** is the Directive.

If you could provide an ID to that input the selection would get simpler. If it is feasible, that is!!